# MongoDB 3.0.1 Replication Setup

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB 3.0.1 version. i am try to setup for mongodb replicaiton in 
our machine. i have use three mongodb in septate machine for replication.

```
machine1 - master
machine2 - slave
machine3 - slave
```

I refer this url `http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set/`

I have configure for every machine in mongodb.conf file

```
replSet = rs1
fork = true
```

and i added two members in master machine using this command

```
rs.add(192.168.1.2)
rs.add(192.168.1.3)
```

but i insert a document in master machine but not replicate other two slave machine. i did check slave machine throw the following error

```
> show dbs
2015-05-18T12:43:22.020+0530 E QUERY    Error: listDatabases failed:{ "note" : "from execCommand", "ok" : 0, "errmsg" : "not master" }
    at Error (<anonymous>)
    at Mongo.getDBs (src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47:15)
    at shellHelper.show (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:630:33)
    at shellHelper (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:524:36)
    at (shellhelp2):1:1 at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:47
> 
> rs.conf()
2015-05-18T12:43:38.692+0530 E QUERY    Error: Could not retrieve replica set config: {
    "info" : "run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set",
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "no replset config has been received",
    "code" : 94
}
    at Function.rs.conf (src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1011:11)
    at (shell):1:4 at src/mongo/shell/utils.js:1011
>
```

Please help me to solve the problem. thanks & Advance.

EDIT:

```
rs1:PRIMARY> rs.conf()
{
    "_id" : "rs1",
    "version" : 4,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "host" : "analyzer-xubuntu:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 1,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "host" : "192.168.1.31:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.75,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "host" : "192.168.1.33:27017",
            "arbiterOnly" : false,
            "buildIndexes" : true,
            "hidden" : false,
            "priority" : 0.5,
            "tags" : {

            },
            "slaveDelay" : 0,
            "votes" : 1
        }
    ],
    "settings" : {
        "chainingAllowed" : true,
        "heartbeatTimeoutSecs" : 10,
        "getLastErrorModes" : {

        },
        "getLastErrorDefaults" : {
            "w" : 1,
            "wtimeout" : 0
        }
    }
}

rs1:PRIMARY> rs.status()
{
    "set" : "rs1",
    "date" : ISODate("2015-05-18T09:07:31.767Z"),
    "myState" : 1,
    "members" : [
        {
            "_id" : 0,
            "name" : "analyzer-xubuntu:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 1,
            "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
            "uptime" : 9236,
            "optime" : Timestamp(1431939509, 2),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("2015-05-18T08:58:29Z"),
            "electionTime" : Timestamp(1431931054, 2),
            "electionDate" : ISODate("2015-05-18T06:37:34Z"),
            "configVersion" : 4,
            "self" : true
        },
        {
            "_id" : 1,
            "name" : "192.168.1.31:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 0,
            "stateStr" : "STARTUP",
            "uptime" : 8953,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-05-18T09:07:29.831Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1,
            "configVersion" : -2
        },
        {
            "_id" : 2,
            "name" : "192.168.1.33:27017",
            "health" : 1,
            "state" : 0,
            "stateStr" : "STARTUP",
            "uptime" : 8946,
            "optime" : Timestamp(0, 0),
            "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2015-05-18T09:07:30.533Z"),
            "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
            "pingMs" : 1,
            "configVersion" : -2
        }
    ],
    "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: `"run rs.initiate(...) if not yet done for the set"`. Did you do that?

Comment: Yes i put the command rs.initiate() in master machine.

Comment: I have one doubt "rs.initiate()" command is run on master machine or other two slave machine

Comment: Yes, you have to *start* with `rs.initiate()`, then call `rs.add()`. Make sure you put the ip addresses in quotation marks, i.e. `rs.add("192.168.1.2")`

Comment: Yes, i added two member that is added success. and i see the rs.status() throw the master machine status is "primary" and other two slave machine status is "Startup". and i insert the data in master machine but not replicate slave machine.

Comment: You have to wait for the 'startup' phase to finish so the secondaries are 'up'. That can take a few minutes.

Comment: ya i am taking more time but not change status startup to secondary.

Comment: Are you sure the machines are reachable from *each other*? Try connecting to the supposed secondary via `mongo` directly from the primary machine, and vice versa. If the firewall is blocking or `mongod` is bound only to the loopback adapters, the rs will never come up.

Comment: Yes i checked the three machine are connecting mongo one to other.

Comment: Please show us what do you get from master node with command `rs.conf()` now. Only if your secondaries shows the status `secondary` can you begin to use them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Let us go step by step.

Your MongoDB config is ok, the rest of work may be done in the shell. I will use machine names instead of IPs.

First connect to `machine1`, and run the following there:

```
> conf = {
            _id: "rs1",
            members:
                      [
                         {_id : 0, host : "machine1:27017"},
                         {_id : 1, host : "machine2:27017"},
                         {_id : 2, host : "machine3:27017"}
                      ]
         }
> rs.initiate(conf)
```

Then just run `rs.slaveOk()` on the secondaries. The `secondaries` will start replicating, and you will be able to query them and see your data, inserted from the `primary`.

Comment: I am reeving the following error  > db.test.find()
Error: error: { "$err" : "not master and slaveOk=false", "code" : 13435 }
> rs.slaveOk()
> db.test.find()
Error: error: {
 "$err" : "not master or secondary; cannot currently read from this replSet member",
 "code" : 13436
}

Comment: did you run `rs.add(...)` **after** running `rs.initiate()`?

Comment: Yes i run first "rs.initiate()" then run "rs.add("machine2:27017")"

Comment: I have updated my answer, please follow the steps and let me know what you get.

Comment: rs1:PRIMARY> rs.initiate(conf)
{
 "info" : "try querying local.system.replset to see current configuration",
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "already initialized",
 "code" : 23
}

Comment: yes, that's because you have already initialised it on your side. This would work on a fresh instance. In your case use `reconfig` instead of `initiate`.

Comment: and then again, run `rs.slaveOk()` on your secondaries, and post what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78072/discussion-between-n9code-and-elango).

Comment: @bagrat Could you please update here about the solution?